# SQL query order by nearness to value

Tags: sql

Is there any way to order by nearness to, say a number? For example, return results sorted by how close column x is to the number 5

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  You can use an expression in the `order by`:

```
order by abs(x - 5)
```